# Getting runtime error "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)" whencalling glCreateShader

Tags: c++, macos, opengl, glfw

I'm trying to compile a shader program, but I'm getting the runtime error message specified above. I've tried for a while to figure out why this is occurring and what it means, but I'm pretty stuck.

Here is the relevant source code:

Main.cpp:

```
#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

#include "shader.hpp"

void initGLFW() {
    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

    #ifdef __APPLE__
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
    #endif
}

GLFWwindow* createWindow(int width, int height) {
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(width, height, "LearnOpenGL", NULL, NULL);
    if (window == NULL) {
        throw runtime_error("Failed to create GLFW window");
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(window, framebuffer_size_callback);
    return window;
}

int main() {
    initGLFW();
    GLFWwindow* window = createWindow(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    initGLAD();
    
    Shader sh {"vertex-shader.txt", "fragment-shader.txt"};
}
```

Shader.cpp

```
unsigned int Shader::compileShader(ShaderType shaderType, const char* srcShader) {
    unsigned int shader {};
    string shaderStr {};
    if (shaderType == ShaderType::vertex) {
        shader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER); // THIS IS WHERE THE RUNTIME ERROR COMES UP
        shaderStr = "Vertex";
    }
    else if (shaderType == ShaderType::fragment) {
        shader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
        shaderStr = "Fragment";
    }
    glShaderSource(shader, 1, &srcShader, nullptr);
    glCompileShader(shader);
    
    // Check for compilation failure
    int  success;
    char infoLog[512];
    glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
    if (!success) {
        glGetShaderInfoLog(shader, 512, nullptr, infoLog);
        ostringstream oss {};
        oss << shaderStr << " shader compilation failed.\n" << infoLog << endl;
        throw runtime_error(oss.str());
    }
    
    return shader;
}

Shader::Shader(const string& vertexShaderFilepath,
               const string& fragmentShaderFilepath)
{
    string srcVertexShader {shaderFromFile(vertexShaderFilepath)};
    string srcFragmentShader {shaderFromFile(fragmentShaderFilepath)};
    const char* srcVS_cstr = srcVertexShader.c_str();
    const char* srcFS_cstr = srcFragmentShader.c_str();
    
    unsigned int vertexShader = compileShader(ShaderType::vertex, srcVS_cstr);
    unsigned int fragmentShader = compileShader(ShaderType::fragment, srcFS_cstr);
    
    shaderProgram = linkShaders(vertexShader, fragmentShader);
    
    glDeleteShader(vertexShader);
    glDeleteShader(fragmentShader);
}

// More stuff in shader.cpp, I only included relevant bits of code.
```

Shader.hpp (mostly irrelevant):

```
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Shader {
public:
    Shader(const string& vertexShaderFilepath,
           const string& fragmentShaderFilepath);
    void activate();
    void activateWithUniform(const string& uniformName, float uniformVal);
    void activateWithUniform(const string& uniformName, int uniformVal);
    
private:
    enum class ShaderType { vertex, fragment };
    
    static string shaderFromFile(const string& filepath);
    static unsigned int compileShader(ShaderType shaderType, const char* srcShader);
    static unsigned int linkShaders(unsigned int shader1, unsigned int shader2);
    
    unsigned int shaderProgram {};
};
```

Heres a screenshot showing what libraries I have linked.

[image: Screenshot to show what library's I'm linking]

I should mention that the shaders are the only thing thats not working in the program - if I comment out the shader, the remainder of the program will output a window with a greenish background. [Here is the full source code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VxnsSOWPVaUa941XjOsBZs_WobGnPRkz/view?usp=sharing), but I hope the pieces of code above is enough to provide the required information.

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: @S.M. https://www.wikihow.com/Be-a-Good-Person

Answer (score 1):

You should choose between GLAD and GLEW, but not use both: GLEW ships with its own set of symbols for OpenGL, but you're not calling glewInit so they remain at 0x0. Either drop the libGLEW library or the GLAD code.

Comment: Thanks, I dropped the GLEW library, but unfortunately I'm still getting the same runtime error.

Comment: Attach a debugger and edit your question with a stack trace of the crashing function. (as text!)